# DOMDocument удалить элемент

Tags: php, dom

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('xml.xml');

//узнаем количество элементов
$length = $xml->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->length;

//если элементы существуют
if ($length) {

    // Выбираем рандомный элемент
    $rand = $xml->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->item(rand(0, $length-1));

    // Выводим текст из поля name
    echo $rand->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // Удаляем этот элемент
    $xml->removeChild($rand);

    // Сохраняем XML
    $xml->saveXML();

}
```

Структура xml

```
<galleries>
  <gallery>
    <name>Название 1</name>
  </gallery>
  <gallery>
    <name>Название 2</name>
  </gallery>
</galleries>
```

Получаем

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Что ему надо?

Comment: попробуйте `$rand->parentNode->removeChild($rand);` вместо `$xml->removeChild($rand);`

Comment: в таком случае ошибок нет, но из xml файла ничего не удаляется

Comment: Либо заюзать `documentElement` ....как в примере с книгами тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/domnode.removechild.php   ..... получится типа `$galleries = $xml->documentElement;  $rand = $galleries->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->item(rand(0, $length-1));  $galleries->removeChild($rand); $xml->saveXML();`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно так же. все выводится как надо. только xml файл остается неизменным

Comment: Точнее так, если после удаления вызвать ченить типа `print_r($galleries);` то действительно ничего нет. Но сам xml файл остается не тронутым. то есть не работает конкретно `$xml->saveXML();` Права на файл аж 777 выставлены

Comment: http://ideone.com/WbGZVc    хмм...

Comment: все, вкурил, `$xml->saveXML(); $xml->save('xml.xml');` Всем спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема устранена двумя вещами:

1. Определением `$xml->documentElement;`
2. **Физическая** запись в файл происходит через `$xml->save('xml.xml');`

---

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('xml.xml');

// Определяем documentElement
$galleries = $xml->documentElement;

//узнаем количество элементов
$length = $galleries->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->length;

//если элементы существуют
if ($length) {

    // Выбираем рандомный элемент
    $rand = $galleries->getElementsByTagName('gallery')->item(rand(0, $length-1));

    // Выводим текст из поля name
    echo $rand->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // Удаляем этот элемент
    $galleries->removeChild($rand);

    // Сохраняем XML
    $xml->saveXML();


    // Сохраняем XML в ФАЙЛ!
    $xml->save('xml.xml');

}
```